# Error in code to flatten a list in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml, flatten

Hello All I am trying to flatten a list in Ocaml. I am a newbie so please pardon me if my mistake is dumb

So for example, if input is [[1];[2;3];[4]]  I should end up with [1;2;3;4].

The idea I am trying to use is as follows
Iterate through the list from the right (Using fold_right) with accumaltor = []
The pseudo code is as follows

```
func flatten(list,  accumalator) 
  For each item from right to left in list 
     If Item is a scalar then n :: accumalator
     Else fi Item is a list of form head :: tail then
               head :: flatten (tail, accumalator).
```

I think that theoretically the algorithm is correct, but please let me know if you disagree.

Now to my OCaml code to implement this algorithm

```
let rec flatten acc x =
    match x with 
           n -> n :: acc
        | [x] -> x :: acc
        | head :: remainder -> 
            head :: ( my_flat acc remainder ) 
 and my_flat = List.fold_right flatten
 ;;

 my_flat [] [[1];[2;3];[4]]
```

The Error I get is the following
     Error: This expression has type 'a but an expression was expected of type
         'a list

The error occurs on the line that reads head :: ( my_flat acc remainder )  in the last pattern in the match statement

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OCaml, all the elements of a list must be the same type.  Thus the value `[1; [2; 3]; 4]` is invalid all by itself.  It contains two elements that are of type `int` and one element of type `int list`.  In essence, your statement of the problem to be solved is impossible.

```
$ ocaml312
        Objective Caml version 3.12.0

# [1; [2; 3]; 4];;
Characters 4-10:
  [1; [2; 3]; 4];;
      ^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type 'a list
       but an expression was expected of type int
```

This sounds like a homework problem, so I'll just say that restricting yourself to lists that are valid in OCaml may make it easier to solve.

**Edit**

OK, the problem can now be solved!

The essence of the reported type error is something like this.  You have your accumulated result `acc` (of type `int list` in the example).  You want to add the list `x` (also of type `int list`) to it.  You've broken `x` into `head` (an `int`) and `remainder` (an `int list`).  As you can see, `remainder` is not a suitable argument for your `my_flat` function.  It wants an `int list list`, i.e., a list of lists of ints.  In fact, your recursive call should almost certainly go to `flatten` and not to `my_flat`.

Another problem I see: the arguments of `List.fold_right` are: a function, a list, and a starting value.  In your test call to `my_flat`, you're supplying the last two in the other order.  The empty list `[]` is your starting value.

I hope this is enough to get you going.  Since you're just starting out with OCaml there will probably be another problem or two before it works.

**Edit 2**

Here are a couple more comments, which might be spoilers if you're still working on your own solution....

A tidier version of your function `my_flat` is in the OCaml standard library under the name `List.flatten`.  It's interesting to look at the implementation:

```
let rec flatten = function
    [] -> []
  | l::r -> l @ flatten r
```

I'd call this a very elegant solution, but unfortunately it's not tail recursive.  So it will consume some (linear) amount of stack space, and might even crash for a very long list.

Here's one based on the same idea, using the standard FP accumulator trick to get tail recursive behavior (as noted by Thomas):

```
let flatten2 ll =
    let rec go acc = function
    | [] -> List.rev acc
    | l :: r -> go (List.rev_append l acc) r
in
    go [] ll
```

As is often the case, the tail recursive version accumulates the result in reverse order, and reverses it at the end.

Comment: Its not a homework problem. Im trying to teach myself Ocaml and practising the problems at http://www.christiankissig.de/cms/index.php/en/programming/28-ocaml/28-99-problems-in-ocaml. Thanks for the advice about type of elements in a list. I corrected my example above

Comment: Great--not a homework problem.  I'll edit my answer above to answer th e new question then.  Regards,

Answer (score 2):

You can start by writing directly your algorithm, by decomposing the base cases of your input value, ie. the input list is either empty, or the head of the input list is empty, or the head of the input list has a head and a tail:

```
let rec flatten = function
  | []          -> []
  | []     :: t -> flatten t
  | (x::y) :: t -> x :: (flatten (y::t))
```

You can then optimize the function, because this code is not tail-recursive and thus will crash when lists become too big. So you can rewrite this by using the usual technique:

```
let flatten list =
  let rec aux accu = function
    | []          -> accu
    | []     :: t -> aux accu t
    | (x::y) :: t -> aux (x::accu) (y::t) in
  List.rev (aux [] list)
```

So my advice is: start by decomposing your problem based on the input types, and then later use accumulators to optimize your code.

Answer (score 2):

I like this one, where the auxiliary function takes the accumulator, the first element of the list of lists, and the rest of the list of lists, it is clearer for me :

```
let flatten list =
  let rec aux acc list1 list2 =
    match list1 with
      | x :: tail -> aux (x :: acc) tail list2
      | [] ->
        match list2 with
          | [] -> List.rev acc
          | x :: tail -> aux acc x tail
  in
  aux [] [] list
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your help
Here is the code I used to solve this problem

```
let flatten list  =
    let rec flatten_each acc x =
        match x with 
               [] -> acc
        |  head :: remainder -> head :: ( flatten_each acc remainder )
in
List.fold_right flatten_each ( List.rev list ) []
;;
```

Edit: as pointed out by Thomas this solution is not tail recursive. Tail recursive version is below

```
let flatten list  =
    let rec flatten_each acc x =
        match x with 
               [] -> acc
            |  head :: remainder -> (flatten_each (acc @ [head]) remainder )
    in
     List.fold_right flatten_each list []
;;
```

Comment: Your function is not tail-recursive, so it does not make sense to use an accumulator here.

Comment: Thanks I fixed that in my solution by adding head to the acc in flatten_each. I put the code above in an edit

Comment: `acc @ [head]`: this is costly (in the size of `acc`) so you should use `head :: acc` and reverse the accumulator in the base case (so you will be linear instead of quadratic)